# Как передать класс?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

У меня есть один большой класс, который я использую в разных Activity. Если Activity завершить и перейти в другую Activity, класс приходится заново создавать. Мне это не нужно, так как переменные будут заново созданы со значениями по умолчанию.

Как передать класс с переменными в другую Activity?

Comment: Есть у меня подозрение, что не класс приходится заново создавать, а объект класса.

Comment: О каком классе, кстати, идет речь? Это модель, хранящая только значения или он включает методы бизнес-логики и если первое, то какого плана значения - вроде глобальных настроек?

Comment: Это небольшой класс, в котором описаны все dialog окна, описаны получение информации из сервера (php), потом его перебора, также авторизации которым нужны сесиии которые хранятся в internet post в томже классе, в классе описан и перебор серверов, получает с тогоже internet под темиже сесиями, а потом начинает дробить на массив и передавать его активностям, вобщем у класса основаная функция "не повторять один и тотже код в разных активностях и хранить переменные которые в глобале класса"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохраняйте значения переменных, которые вам будут нужны через SharedPreferences например. При переходе на другую активити сохраняетесь, а при создании класса заново проверяйте: если нужных вам переменных в памяти нет, значит присваивайте значения по умолчанию, если есть, то загружайте, то что вы сохранили.

Comment: Ага, у меня еще используется htttp и пост, в котором свои сесии которые надо чтоб все сохранилось, не вариант.

Comment: Может заменить класс на сервис? Тогда все что делается в классе будет продолжать выполняться в фоне, а к сервису можете обращаться через сообщения.

Comment: Возможно, подскажешь как?

Comment: Сама с этим мучилась не один день, но в итоге вроде работает как надо. Кода много, поэтому вот ссылки, делала все как там: 
Здесь как подключить сервис - http://microsin.net/programming/android/services.html
Тут как обмениваться данными - http://m.habrahabr.ru/post/157063/?mobile=yes

Answer (score 3):

И [синглтон](https://rsdn.ru/forum/design/2615563.1) и ["божественный" объект](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82) являются антипатернами, особенно в android-разработке - их использования надо пытаться избегать во избежании проблем (с одной из которых вы столкнулись). Не надо пытаться решать проблему костылями, если решение не работает (создает проблемы) нужно искать другое решение.

Есть определенные концепции ООП программирования, которые определяют структуру приложения, например [принципы SOLID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)).
В android-разработке, как нигде актуальна архитектура, когда объекты делают свою маленькую работу, сохраняют\передают дальше промежуточные **результаты** и с честью погибают. Это связано с особенностями жизненного цикла android-приложений и негарантированного существования хостовых объектов.

В общем вы все делаете неправильно, архитектура android-приложения строится на других принципах. В общих случаях в ней не должно быть объектов, живущих дольше активити, которая их породила.
Коммуникации между разными активити, разными классами, активити и классами, должны происходить передачей данных (куда входят и классы-модели) или сохранятся для промежуточного хранения и последующего извлечения.Для этого есть специальные инструменты: интенты, рисиверы, листенеры с обратным вызовом и др. гарантирующие передачу данных не привязанную к существованию отправителя.
Для долгосрочного хранения: SharedPreferences, SQLite, JSON в файле и др.

PS: передавать класс с бизнес-логикой между активити вообще печальная затея

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте паттерн Singleton.
Singleton гарантирует, что у класса есть только один экземпляр, и предоставляет к нему глобальную точку доступа.
http://m.habrahabr.ru/post/27108/

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).

Answer (score 0):

А что вам мешает передать объект вашего класса через **Intent** методом **Intent.putExtra()**?
Потом вы сможете его достать методом **Intent.getParcalable()** с приведением к типу вашего класса
Правда вам придётся наследовать интерфейс Parcalable для вашего класса.
Также вы можете использовать сериализацию

Comment: Примера хотябы м

Comment: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/132-urok-69-peredaem-parcelable-obekty-s-pomoschju-intent.html